# Log-scale for regression, graph, or both?

Tags: regression, linear-model, interpretation, graphical-model

The below graphs denotes the relationship between prices (relative to the United States, so that US=1) and economic out per capita (also relative to the US, so that US=1).

The author graphs the relationship in level-level terms, but overlays a regression in log-log terms.

In order to claim a positive association between the two variables being plotted, should one rely on the visual graph which is level-level, the regression which is in logs-logs, or both? What if ther relationship between the variables is only positive linear in log-log terms, but not level-level? Likewise, what about level-log?

I understand logs are often used to linearize a relationship, but I have my doubts on whether it's fair to characterize a relationship as linear if it is only linear after a log transformation.

[image: Regression line in log-log; but not graph]

Comment: More to the point is how convincingly the plot shows that the regression curve is a terrible fit!  The evidence comes from noting that almost all residuals in the right side of the plot are positive.

Comment: Good observation. The author acknowledges this by claiming that "it is clear from the figure that there is a positive relationship between country income and prices [...]" and then adding that: "inspection of the figure also indicates that whereas the relationship between income and prices is quite striking over the fill data, it is less impressive when one looks at either rich countries as a groups, or at developing countries as group. Regression evidence confirms this observation."

Comment: I think some concave transformation (log, or sqrt) for response is desired, as the variance is non constant? Off-topic - tough life in Gabon

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad. Very true, and I believe I've seen this graph plotted that way. In any case, my initial question still stands: can one claim a positive association between two variables if, say, if they are positively associated only after transforming one, or both, variables?

Comment: You are asking several different questions: one about whether to plot on log scales on one or both axes, another about whether a relationship between logged variables can be called linear, Can you clarify what your main doubt is?

Comment: I would be interested in reading your take on both of these questions. I find them to be interrelated for this example.

Comment: @mdewey. Any comments on this would be appreciated.